# EF6 LinqPad is loading everything

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

I've just updated my project to EF6. I am still using ObjectContext. The app itself compiles and works correctly

In LINQPad though, when I try to load an entity, e.g. `BlogPosts.FirstOrDefault()`, LINQPad loads every single related entity in the graph. Needless to say, this means it takes forever and I am getting "out of memory" problems.

Is there an obvious reason why this should be happening? As far as I know lazy loading is enabled, and I've even tried adding `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled=true;` in LINQPad with no difference.

I'm using the latest LINQPad Beta.

Comment: I'll look into this - in the meantime, if you dump the results to grids (click the 'Grids' toolbar button), it will enumerate only one level at a time.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I found migrating to DbContext has fixed it.